# Three.js: Light on decal look weird

Tags: three.js

I need help about decal light point issue. I added decal into main object then light it look weird on decal that i added.

When i move camera to bottom for object light it fine but for decal it away turn to black. 
If i turn camera to top then decal can turn to normal color of image.

Please see in example picture you will see what i mean.

(Object base on MeshPhongMaterial)
(Decal texture build from MeshPhongMaterial then push to DecalGeometry)

[Front Camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgJ8V.png)

[Top Camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8nnp.png)

[Bottom Camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJvHr.png)

[Side + Top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcCeE.png)

Thank you.

---

[VertexNormalHelper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgR0v.png)

Comment: Looks like the normal's might be wrong on the decal.
Can you try and visualize the normal's of the decal to verify they are correct? (ie via this: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/helpers/VertexNormalsHelper)?

Comment: @DacreDenny Thank you for advice. I already did and attach result. Please have a look.

Comment: Can you provide a [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/) of your code? Otherwise it will be hard to investigate the issue.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I just fixed by change light method. The issue on this case is ... Because default model (OBJ) it not straight up object and not center position. Then after i transform them to center and straight up the light it not follow transform that why it reflex weird.